# Displaying variables inside message statement in ABAP

Tags: abap

How do I display a variable inside a message statement, without using a message class?

```
IF acct_bal < min_bal.
    MESSAGE 'customer balance less than minimum. Balance-->', acct_bal TYPE 'E'.
ENDIF.
```

My program has a syntax error since the system does not allow `acct_bal` into the message statement. I don't want to use a message class with placeholders to do this:

```
Program z_test.
DATA: acct_bal TYPE 'I' value 10,
min_bal TYPE 'I' value 100.
IF acct_bal < min_bal.
    MESSAGE 'customer balance less than minimum. Balance-->', acct_bal type 'E'.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: Note that using a numbered message from a message class should always be the preferred way to do messages. When the message appears in production later and nobody knows why, then using a message class makes it a lot easier to find out from what section of code is responsible. You can check the message class and number from the long text popup and use the "where used" list or you can set a dynamic debugger breakpoint that stops when that specific message gets thrown. And you can also write a long-text that provides additional guidance for end-users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
MESSAGE lv_variable && 'Your text'.
```

Important are the two `&&` between the variable and the text.

Answer (score 8):

There are lots of possibilities. Here are some of them.

What you want can be achieved using a [string template](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstring_templates.htm) (works as of ABAP 7.02) e.g. `|text and { variable }|`:

```
MESSAGE |customer balance less than minimum. Balance-->{ acct_bal }| TYPE 'E'.
```

Or if you want your message to be translatable via a text symbol:

```
MESSAGE |{ replace( val = 'customer balance less than minimum. Balance-->&1'(001)
                    sub = '&1' with = acct_bal ) }| TYPE 'E'.
```

Or if you want your message be translatable via a message class, create a Message ID via transaction code `SE91`, with the text `customer balance less than minimum. Balance-->&1`, for instance the ID `001` in the message class `ZMSGCLASS`:

```
MESSAGE e001(zmsgclass) TYPE 'E' WITH acct_bal.
```

Etc.

More information in [ABAP Documentation - MESSAGE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapmessage.htm).

Comment: I have used concatenate to form a string and use it in message.

Comment: CONCATENATE 'Balance < Min_Bal'  lv_customer_account_balance  '<'  lv_customer_account_min_bal INTO lv_message.

MESSAGE  lv_message TYPE 'E'.

Comment: Why not the short way `MESSAGE |Balance < Min_Bal { lv_customer_account_balance } < { lv_customer_account_min_bal }| TYPE 'E'.` ?